# Need help making an image appear on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a thing where when you click on the hidden image it appears. Every time that I do it, though, the image just stays hidden. I know that I am actually clicking the image because I made it so that it follows under my cursor. It also works in reverse. If the image is visible and I click on it it turns invisible.
Here is my HTML:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let body = document.querySelector('body');
  let boom = document.getElementById('boom');
  let left = e.pageX;
  let top = e.pageY;
  boom.style.left = left + 'px';
  boom.style.top = top + 'px';
});

function animation(){
  var boom = document.getElementById("boom");
    boom.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("boom").src = "file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/Atom/rootfolder/Boom%20Salamon/Salamon.png";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

header {
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 13px
}

#boom{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Boom! Salamon</title>
    </head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <body>
        <header>
            <h2 style="color: white; text-align: center">Boom! Salamon.<br>Click in the area below to witness the magic!</h2>
        </header>
        <img onclick='animation()' id="boom" src='file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/Atom/rootfolder/Boom%20Salamon/Boom!.png' height="250" width="250"></img>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's happening?

Comment: Nothing in your code has anything to unhide the image at any point. So once it is clicked, it is hidden as your code intends. Add code to unhide the image.

Answer (score 1):

yes as @Abin mentioned you have not added any code to unhide it I have modified your
html and js file to add this functionality like when you click on text it will be visible again.

Note: i have added that visible condition on click of header text but you can define it anywhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
        <title>Boom! Salamon</title>
    </head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <body>
        <header>
            <h2 id='clickme' style="color: white; text-align: center">Boom! Salamon.<br>Click here to witness the magic!</h2>
        </header>
        <img onclick='animation()' id="boom" src='file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/Atom/rootfolder/Boom%20Salamon/Boom!.png' height="250" width="250"></img>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let body = document.querySelector('body');
  let boom = document.getElementById('boom');
  let left = e.pageX;
  let top = e.pageY;
  boom.style.left = left + 'px';
  boom.style.top = top + 'px';
});

function animation(){
  var boom = document.getElementById("boom");
    
    boom.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("boom").src = 'file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/Atom/rootfolder/Boom%20Salamon/Salamon.png';
}

document.getElementById("clickme").onclick = function() {
    boom.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

in above i have used pure js.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing in the code you have provided to unhide the image, I have added a sample code that works as per your req. Click on the text, and the image will appear on the bottom.

```js
/* document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  let body = document.querySelector('body');
  let boom = document.getElementById('boom');
  let left = e.pageX;
  let top = e.pageY;
  boom.style.left = left + 'px';
  boom.style.top = top + 'px';
});
*/

var clickEl = document.getElementById('click-el')

clickEl.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var imgEl = document.getElementById('boom');
  imgEl.style.display = 'block';
})

/*
function animation(){
  var boom = document.getElementById("boom");
    boom.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("boom").src = "file:///C:/Users/domin/Desktop/Atom/rootfolder/Boom%20Salamon/Salamon.png";
} */
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

header {
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 13px
}

#boom{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
        <header>
            <h2 id='click-el' style="color: white; text-align: center">Boom! Salamon.<br>Click here to witness the magic!</h2>
        </header>
        <img onclick='animation()' id="boom" src='https://static.remove.bg/sample-gallery/graphics/bird-thumbnail.jpg' height="250" width="250"/>
```